# How can the derivative of the Euclidean norm be exhibited without considering partial derivatives?

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be given by $f(x) = \|x\|$.

I would like to show that $Df(a)h = \frac{a\cdot h}{\|a\|}$ without resorting to using partial derivatives. I considered the expression

$\frac{\|a+h\| - \|a\| - \frac{a \cdot h}{\|a\|}}{\|h\|} = \frac{\|a+h\| - \|a\|}{\|h\|} - \frac{a \cdot h}{\|a\|\|h\|}$

which I was sure I could manipulate to show that this approached $0$ as $h \to 0$ using some combination of the triangle inequalities and possibly Cauchy-Schwarz (looking at the last term in the expression), but I was unable to pin it down.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the fact that $\Vert x\Vert$ is the composition of $x\mapsto x\cdot x$ with the function $0\leq p\mapsto \sqrt{p}$, and apply the chain rule.